# GWT - Methods in onModuleLoad() called multiple times

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-visualization

I'm trying to write a simple application to display chart data. I want to display some data as soon as the user loads the page, so I'm getting data & drawing tables inside of the `Runnable` as described in the gwt-visualization [Getting Started](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted).

Things seem to work alright, except charts tend to get loaded more than once. Below is my `onModuleLoad()`.

```
    private final StatisticsServiceAsync statisticsService = GWT.create(StatisticsService.class);
    GWTBeanFactory factory = GWT.create(GWTBeanFactory.class);
    DataTable locationData;
    AnnotatedTimeLine atl;
    GeoMap usMap;
    TextBox storeField;
    Button log10Button;
    DateRange durationChartRange;
    String eusrJson = null;
    Button b;
    HTML last1000Html;

    public void onModuleLoad() {

    storeField = new TextBox();
    storeField.setText("Enter a store");
    storeField.addKeyDownHandler(new MyKeyHandler());
    b = new Button("Get Stats!");
    log10Button = new Button("Show Log10 Scale");
    log10Button.addClickHandler(new Log10ClickHandler());
    b.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler());

    last1000Html = new HTML();
    getLast1000Avg();

    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            storeDurationData = DataTable.create();
            storeDurationDataLog10 = DataTable.create();

            RootPanel.get("storeDurationDiv").add(storeField);
            RootPanel.get("storeDurationDiv").add(b);
            RootPanel.get("storeDurationDiv").add(log10Button);
            RootPanel.get("storeDurationDiv").add(last1000Html);

            log10Button.setVisible(false);

            // Get initial Data
            getAvgByRegion();
            getLast1000Avg();
            Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new RepeatingCommand() {
                @Override
                public boolean execute() {
                    getLast1000Avg();
                    return true;
                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    };

    // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called
    // when loading is done.
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, AnnotatedTimeLine.PACKAGE);
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, GeoMap.PACKAGE);
}
```

All of the "simple" elements seem to get populated correctly, as the `Button`, `HTML`, and `TextBox` all get placed appropriately (which used to be inside of `run`, they're where they are now as a result of debugging previous errors). However, the `GeoMap` gets placed twice, and looking at the logging you can tell that the `Runnable`'s `run` is being executed at least twice, which seems reasonable, but I don't know how to keep it from adding twice.

I'm probably screwing up something with the Async stuff, but I'm new and confused. Below is my `getAvgByRegion()` method:

```
    private void getAvgByRegion() {
    statisticsService.getEusrForRegion(new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println(":(");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            createLocTable();
            DataTable dt = parseEusrLocations(result);
            usMap = new GeoMap(dt, createGeoMapOptions());
            usMap.setSize("800px", "600px");
            RootPanel.get("storeDurationDiv").add(usMap);
        }

    });
}
```

Any advice on how best to work with GWT is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you call `VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi` twice, so the `onLoadCallback` will be run twice (I don't know GWT Google Apis, this is a supposition).

`onLoadCallback` calls `getAvgByRegion`, so that one will get called twice too; and it gets data and in the callback creates a new `GeoMap` and **adds** it to the `RootPanel.get("storeDurationDiv")`, so you get two `GeoMap`s on the screen.

The other widgets(`storeField`, etc.) are created only once, so `add`ing them repeatedly is not a problem (except performance-wise), as they'll first be removed from their current parent before being added to the new one (which in this case is the same)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Previously, it was complaining when I hadn't loaded the GeoMap visualization API, so I went ahead and did it as above. As you suggested, however, this was causing it to load twice. Going from Google's sample it's not immediately apparent that `VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi` has support for varargs. I changed my load to `VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, AnnotatedTimeLine.PACKAGE, GeoMap.PACKAGE);` and it's working like a charm.